# Woocommerce - search in product category by keyword

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is my search form. Im use woocommerce. And need to search products by keywords and categories.

```
         <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="search-bar-select hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <span></span>
                <i></i>
                <select name="category">
                <option value="" class="search-bar-select-text"><?php _e('[:ru]Все категории[:ro]Toate categoriile') ?></option>
                <?php foreach(woo_category_list(FALSE) as $category) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="search-bar-input">
                <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('[:ru]Поиск по сайту ...[:ro]Căutare pe site') ?>" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
            <div class="search-bar-btn">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

this is my filter code

```
function advanced_search_query($query)
{
if($query->is_search()) {
    // category terms search.
    if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
        $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($_GET['category']) )
        ));
    }    
    return $query;
}
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

but wordpress show all products from all categories by keyword.
WHAT IS WRONG?

Comment: If you put a `var_dump($_GET)` inside of your filter function, what does it output?

Comment: Also as a note - you do not need to `return $query`.

Comment: Last tip - you may want to - instead of `$query->set` - use the structure recommended here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98143

Answer (score 0):

you can do this **with out hooks**.

simply change the "**name**" attribute for the category input to "**product_cat**".

so remove the hook and change your code like this:

```
  <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="search-bar-select hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <strong textspan></span>
                <i></i>
                <select name="product_cat">
                <option value="" class="search-bar-select-text"><?php _e('[:ru]Все категории[:ro]Toate categoriile') ?></option>
                <?php foreach(woo_category_list(FALSE) as $category) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="search-bar-input">
                <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('[:ru]Поиск по сайту ...[:ro]Căutare pe site') ?>" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
            <div class="search-bar-btn">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

to list all the product cats in a dropdown list, use this method:

(*instead of* foreach(woo_category_list(FALSE) as $category) )

```
<?php 
$args = array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'name' => 'product_cat',
   'value_field' => 'slug',
   'class' => 'something'
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

?>
```